# I can not print because laptop can not find printers

Tags: printing

I used to print a lot of documents in the beginning on my Dell laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Now suddenly my laptop lost access to all printers that I used for printing before.

Comment: You might need to provide some more info. How do you connect to the printer? Has something changed? Restart laptop/printer and when connecting wireless to the printer you might also do a reset of the router and check if all settings are correct.

Comment: What does `service cups status` show you? Also, point a browser at `http://localhost:631/admin` and click on `Find New Printers`